# Inherit from a class not imported yet?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, python-import, python-module

I have a modules.py file defining several base classes.

One of these base classe inherit itself from a class defined in another module:

```
class MyClass(torch.nn.Module):
    ...
```

However, I'd prefer not to `import torch` in that modules.py file yet, because it's quite a big library, and this modules.py file is used by multiple processes, which would mean all of these processes would also have to `import torch`, leading quickly to an overflow (been there, done that).

Is there a way to define `MyClass` and specify it's based on `torch.nn.Module` without having to `import torch` just yet, and let the processes who really need the torch module do the import themselves ? So the other processes not needing `MyClass` could just ignore it's there and not try to resolve it, for instance ?

Comment: Move ``MyClass`` to its own module and only import it when needed?

Comment: Does this work `from torch import MyClass`?

Comment: Can't you do `from torch.nm import Module` to import just the needed class and not the rest.

Comment: `import` remember loaded modules and next `import torch` shouldn't load module again.

Comment: @MikeScotty that's what I'll do if there are no other way, but that's less elegant in my case

@PCM @BR doesn't work, because the file where Module is defined also has an `import torch`

@furas I'm dealing with multiple, independent processes here, so they don't share the same memory space

Answer (score 1):

There is a rather advanced way to simulate dynamic import by building a dummy class and importing the real module and overwriting its attributes on first call of its `__new__` special method.

Demo:

module A.py:

```
class Attempt:
    _changed = False
    def __new__(cls, i):
        if not cls._changed:
            cls._changed = True
            import B
            for name, member in B.B.__dict__.items():
                if name not in ('__dict__', '__module__'):
                    setattr(cls, name, member)
        return object.__new__(cls)
```

module B.py:

```
print('importing module B')

class B:
    a = 5
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'B({self.i})'
```

You can then use it that way:

```
>>> import A
>>> a = A.Attempt(2)
importing module B
>>> b = A.Attempt(3)
>>> print(a,b)
B(2) B(3)
```

Which proves that the module B is only loaded at creation of the first object.

Comment: Quite hacky but interesting workaround !

Comment: @RobinLobel: I would not advise to use that without thinking twice whether it is really required, because it is indeed hacky... But it does what you asked for ;-)